# Ubuntu upstart script for tracd hangs on start/stop

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, trac, init

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) upstart script to manage Trac's built in web server as an upstream server for nginx.

Here is my init script `/etc/init/tracd.conf`. I used http://codebyko.se/2010/11/26/tracd-with-upstart-on-ubuntu/ (first and only google result for 'upstart' and 'tracd') as a starting point:

```
description "Tracd Web Server"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

expect daemon

exec sudo tracd -d -p 8000 -b 192.168.1.2 --user=www-data --group=www-data /trac/proj
```

Whenever I run this through `sudo service tracd start` or `sudo service tracd stop`, it simply hangs and never returns. `sudo service tracd status` returns "tracd start/killed, process 748". The upstart log `/var/log/upstart/tracd.log` contains no information, nor does syslog.

If I simply copy and paste `sudo tracd -d -p 8000 -b 192.168.1.2 --user=www-data --group=www-data /trac/proj` on the command line, the server runs fine.

Here is what I've tried:

- Googled -- hard. Read through Ubuntu's upstart cookbook page and all of the Trac guides: [TracInstall](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall), [TracNginxRecipe](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracNginxRecipe), [TracStandalone](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone)
- Use `expect fork`, `expect daemon` or omit the `expect` line entirely.
- Use `script`/`end script` block around the exec line.
- Use `setuid www-data`/`setgid www-data`.
- Use `sudo -u www-data` and even `sudo su www-data -c "..."`
- Created a www-data writable dir  `/var/run/trac/` and specified `--pidfile=/var/run/trac/tracd.pid`.
- Examine output from `sudo -u www-data env` to see if there are any special environment variables from command line, because it's running fine when executed from the shell. Trac doesn't appear to rely on any environment variables.
- Used the much more verbose, but identical command: `sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/tracd --daemonize --port=8000 --hostname=192.168.1.2 --user=www-data --group=www-data /trac/proj`
- Checked for zombie tracd daemons with `ps -aux | grep trac`.

Things I haven't tried:

- Abandon upstart for an init.d script.

#### EDIT: Fixed

Removing the `--daemonize` flag seems to have fixed it. Thanks Mike! Here's my working upstart script:

```
description "Trac Web Server"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

setuid www-data
setgid www-data

exec tracd -p 8000 -b 192.168.1.2 /trac/proj
```

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS; updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the sudo since tracd is setting the user/group

```
description "Tracd Web Server"

start on startup
stop on shutdown


expect daemon

exec tracd -p 8000 -b 192.168.1.2 --user=www-data --group=www-data /trac/proj
```

If that doesn't work try to set the running user in upstart via `setuid` and `setgid`

```
description "Tracd Web Server"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

setuid www-data
setgid www-data

expect daemon

exec tracd -p 8000 -b 192.168.1.2 /trac/proj
```

EDIT

remove the -d flag.. upstart you cannot run something as a daemon it needs to act like it is running in the foreground

Comment: I tried both, but the problem is the fact that the same command (from `exec ` on) works on the shell, but in a service definition, `sudo service tracd start` or `stop` just hangs.

Comment: ohh i see the problem.. see the edit

Comment: so the -d flag needs to be removed.. upstart likes things to run in the foreground. It is hanging probably due to the -d flag

Comment: glad that was the problem